# Store multiple sizes of an image or just store the main and resize?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, storage

I'm working on a CMS and I'm trying to figure out the common practice for doing a REST style image request. I have three sizes, small, medium, and full. My thought is to store only the full and write a function that will resize on each page request. This has obvious cpu costs. The other end is that I could store all three sizes and only calculate on upload, this seems to waste space.

My environment is an intranet, so relatively low requests and a high number of images stored. Thoughts?

Note: I realize I don't have to really worry too much since it's intranet and either solution will work, just wondering which would be preferred for knowledge sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to maintain a cache of resized images. Serve up the ones that are available. Create new ones if they are not available. Delete images that have not been requested for a while.

This will be a compromise between the CPU and storage issues.

Comment: I like it. It works well since most images are never seen again after their first 3 weeks in production. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Store the full then generate the other sizes as needed and cache them; page processing will be slowed down a little on the first request but then the cached version would be used for all subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

Since you think there will be many images stored and not very many requests, I'd go with the resize-on-the-fly solution, since it sounds like you *already know* storage space will be the bigger issue.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could set up an MRU (most recently used) cache of the *n*-most commonly requested resized images, but again, if low number of requests this would probably be overkill - but still might be a fun project! ;)

Answer (score 1):

One of the key points of REST and the usage over the standard HTTP verbs is that it supports caching; I think that would support the intent to do dynamic resizing.  It's really a question of tradeoff of storage space vs. request-time computation, though.

Answer (score 0):

If system load is not an issue (assuming a low volume intranet app) I would go with storing the full size image and scale it at runtime. That way if you ever need other sizes, you won't need to replace all of your images.

But as you stated above, understand the trade offs and make some good estimations of systems load, disk space, likelihood of requirements changing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question yourself, it's a CPU-Space tradeoff.
You know the costs of each path, just ask yourself, which resource is more costly for you.